# How to use if Structure in batch file correctly?

Tags: batch-file

Well, I am kinda lost in using IF in windows batch. I should be easy thou, but it doesn't work so far.

This is a very very simple example, but I don't get any output so far.

Where is my mistake?
Thank you for your help!

```
@echo off

set var1=1
set var2=1

if var1==1 (
    echo hallo welt1
)

if var2==1 (
    echo hallo welt2
)

Pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string `var1` is not the content of the variable, it's just the string `var1`. You have to expand the variable by using `%var1%`. This is replaced with the variable's value while parsing, so your `if` statement should work.

Comment: Thank you! That was indeed a problem, but not the main thing, because in my original file I had the %% used, only for the minimal example i forgot them.

But in my main program I had comments and I used :: to initiate them. Changing that to REM made it work!

Comment: @thowi, I suggest in the future you read, [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before you ask another question.